# Looping through xml and store data to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

XML Output is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Country code="GR">

   <Regions>
      <Region translation="null">Athens Airport</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Athens Coast</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Athens Suburbs-Attica</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Athens</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Central Greece-Etoloakarnania</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Central Greece-Evritania</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Central Greece-Ioannina</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Central Greece-Karditsa</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Central Greece-Larissa</Region>
      <Region translation="null">Central Greece-Magnissia</Region>
   </Regions>
</Country>
```

Each Region has cities and as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Country code="GR">
   <Cities>
      <City translation="null">Acharnes</City>
      <City translation="null">Achladies</City>
      <City translation="null">Achladochori</City>
      <City translation="null">Adamas</City>
      <City translation="null">Afandou</City>
      <City translation="null">Afiartis</City>
      <City translation="null">Agali</City>
      <City translation="null">Aghia Anna</City>
      <City translation="null">Aghia Paraskevi</City>
</Cities>
```

What I need is to insert all the cities under every region and country to a table.
A country has many region and a region has multiple cities.
What I tried is

```
$regions = array("GR" => "Greece", "BR" => "Brazil", "US" => "USA");

foreach ($regions as $code => $country) {

    $url = "URL which gives an xml output"
    file_put_contents($code . '.xml', file_get_contents($url));

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($code".xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
        $region = $row->Region;
    }
}
```

How can I loop through and save it in mysql..?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$regions = array("US" => "USA", "FR" => "France", "AU" => "Australia");
    foreach ($regions as $code => $country) {

        $url = "URL oes here which ives an xml output";
        file_put_contents($code . '.xml', file_get_contents($url));

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($code.".xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

            foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
                $region = $row->Region;

                    foreach ($region as $RegionName) {

                        $cityURL = "URL which gives city xml data for regions";

                        file_put_contents('Cities.xml', file_get_contents($cityURL));

                        $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("Cities.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

                            foreach ($xml2->children() as $row2) {
                                $city = $row2->City;

                                    foreach ($city as $cityName) {

                                    //Code to add to database

                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

This will do the job exactly as required.

Answer (score 0):

If your .XML output is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Country>
    <Code></Code>
    <Regions>
        <Region>
            <Name></Name>
            <Cities>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
            </Cities>
        </Region>
        <Region>
            <Name></Name>
            <Cities>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
            </Cities>
        </Region>
    </Regions>
</Country>
<Country>
    <Code></Code>
    <Regions>
        <Region>
            <Name></Name>
            <Cities>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
            </Cities>
        </Region>
        <Region>
            <Name></Name>
            <Cities>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
                <City></City>
            </Cities>
        </Region>
    </Regions>
</Country>
```

You should do this in your php:

```
$url = "URL which gives an xml output";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
foreach($xml->children() as $country){
    // Query to insert the country into the countries table by $country->Code
    foreach($country->Regions as $region){
        // Query to insert the region into the regions table by $country->Code and $region->Name
        foreach($region->Cities as $city){
            // Query to insert the city into the cities table by $country->Code and $region->Name and $city->City
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Country code="GR">
   <Cities>
      <City>Alimos</City>
      <City>Anavyssos</City>
      <City>Glyfada</City>
      <City>Lagonissi</City>
      <City>Palaio Faliro</City>
      <City>Sounio</City>
      <City>Voula</City>
      <City>Vouliagmeni</City>
   </Cities>
</Country>

Actually for every region there is such XML output.
NOT INSIDE REGION TAGS AS IN YOUR XML

Comment: i GET EVERY REGION IN FOREACH AND PARSE IT TO GET XML OUTPUT OF CITIES. NOW I NEED TO CAPTURE ALL CITIES INSIDE EACH REGION